# Django multiple sites using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am serving multiple websites using nginx and gunicorn and I would like to add another one. Sadly my lack of experience is limiting me, I have some experience with webdesign but always struggle on the server side...|-( (I am using Django because of my Python preference in scientific analysis).

My problem: The new site seems to refer to the port used by another. Checking the gunicorn status I see that the site is running although nginx seems to be unable to refer to the correct Django folder. Could someone point me in the right direction? I have been looking around for the last hour or so...

(I didn't include any code for now as I am not sure where the error might lie at this point...)

Next day update: So I finally came across a post mentioning that the origin of the error might lie on the browser side. I deleted my recent history, this has fixed the error. I believe I somehow loaded a https certificate belonging to one of the other sites, this is no longer the case!

Comment: `unable to refer to the correct Django folder` what it means? static directory or other folder

Comment: It seemed to refer to the wrong Django project (wrong choice of words before, my apologies). But I was finally able to find the origin of this error, I’ll update my original post with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the solution, it was a browser side fix. The answer is provided in an update to the original question.